Best Approach To Demodulate AM Signal
I have a way of direct sampling negative polarities and positive polarities using an ADC. I store the values separately. When I use Python to FFT, either polarity samples, the returned results can be seen in the image. I see they have both contain different carrier frequencies, and would like to begin demodulating the one with the most magnitude found in the positive FFT output.
Using Python, what approach would work to get this done. I understand that working with IQ samples is the better approach. Would a Hartley Transform IQ samples or the FFT IQ samples work best to begin the demodulation process.
Needed Information

Center Frequency: 70582.89 Hz
Bandwidth: 10 kHz
Sample Rate: 1MHz



I don't quite understand the motivation to sample "positive polarities" and "negative polarities", why not just sample the signal as we can easily demodulate AM directly from that? Also from your FFT it appears that the signal hasn't been properly anti-alias filtered prior to sampling. Is the signal a passband signal or baseband signal? A block diagram or more details of what you know about the signal and what is motivating your approach would help (what is the carrier frequency, what is the bandwidth, is this large carrier AM or suppressed carrier AM etc)

The positive polarity is from a non-inverting opamp connected to the ADC, and the negative polarity is an inverting opamp connected to the ADC.
I could bring both real-valued sample values in as a complex signal this way, which would make it a true bipolar complex signal, however, I haven't because I wanted to see the difference in the FFT results for each polarities.
I have not applied anti-aliasing yet. I will try that suggestion and update the original question with the results.

I have the MCU that does the sampling, configured to use the built-in 64 coefficient FIR filter. From my understanding this is the same as an anti-aliasing filter. In addition, I have my Python code remove DC :)

It’s not clear yet how that would be a complex signal if you did as you suggest (the sampling rate would need to be much higher than the BW), or why you can’t just sample the one signal. Could you show those details as an actual update to your post? (A diagram would be best if possible, include what the carrier freq is, modulation bandwidth and how you plan with your approach to demod. The anti-alias filter that is needed is an analog filter that is before the ADC. The FIR filter can be an different anti-alias filter if there is a subsequent downsampling after that filter for that purpose

I can provide an answer but want to have it be specific to your details, and we should make sure those are in your post directly so other readers don’t have to go through all the comments to understand the question, thanks!

I updated the question above with the needed information. Thanks!

Please also add if it is DSB-SC AM, or large carrier AM (and if so what the modulation index is). or SSB etc.  Is this indeed an analog demodulation such as 10 KHz audio?
